# ImageIO.write not working after LeptUtils.convertPixToImage

Tags: java, image-processing, leptonica

I create some app which use Tessaract and before use OCR I use Leptutils to remove horizontal lines from image. In Eclipse all works fine, but when I export in jar file, programm stucks on ImageIO.write. This function is done under its own threath. When I use these operations under main threath, all works fine. What is wrong?
Here is some code:

```
PDFRenderer pdfRenderer = new PDFRenderer(document);
int lpp = document.getNumberOfPages();
Cikls=0; Aplis =1;
ST_OCR1(lpp); //Run process monitor
Pix bild = null;
Pix bild1 = null;
for(int i = 0; i < lpp; ++i) {
    Cikls=i;

 BufferedImage image = pdfRenderer.renderImageWithDPI(i, dpi, ImageType.GRAY);

 try { bild =LeptUtils.convertImageToPix(image); logger.info("convertImageToPix");}
    catch (IOException e) {logger.info("Exeption convertImageToPix");}
 bild1 = LeptUtils.removeLines(bild);
 try {image = LeptUtils.convertPixToImage(bild1); logger.info("convertPixToImage");}
    catch (IOException e) {logger.info("Exeption convertPixToImage");}
 try {ImageIO.write(image, Jpg, new File(Cels + "\\Temp\\"+ "p"+i+"."+Jpg)); logger.info("ImageIO.write");} // <- Here programm stuck!!!!!!!!!
    catch (IOException e) { logger.info("Exeption ImageIO.write");}

}
  //release Pix resource
PointerByReference pRef = new PointerByReference();
pRef.setValue(bild.getPointer());
Leptonica1.pixDestroy(pRef);
pRef.setValue(bild1.getPointer());
Leptonica1.pixDestroy(pRef);
document.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved!
I use:
Leptonica1.pixWrite(Cels + "\Temp\p"+i+"."+Jpg, bild1, ILeptonica.IFF_TIFF);
instead of:
image = LeptUtils.convertPixToImage(bild1);
ImageIO.write(image, Jpg, new File(Cels + "\Temp\"+ "p"+i+"."+Jpg));